Multiple transmission attack on NTRU
I am trying to understand the NTRU scheme from [HPS98], but I must have a misunderstanding because I think the scheme described there is incorrect, which it probably isn't. I also cannot follow the multiple transmission attack described in Section 3.3 of the paper, both essentially for the same reason, namely the invertibility of polynomials in a certain ring.

Question about the correctness:

The key creation protocol described on page 3 defines the public key as follows. Let $d$ be an integer and let $L_g$ be the set of polynomials with exactly $d$ coefficients equal to $1$ and $d$ coefficients equal to $-1$ (see Section 2.2 for this definition of $L_g$).
The public key is a polynomial $h \in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N-1)$, where
$$
h = F_q \cdot g
$$
for $F_q = f^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N-1)$ with $f, g$ chosen at random from $L_g$.
I think that $f$ cannot have an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X-1)$, so $F_q$ does not exist. This is because $L_g$ is defined such that we cannot have $\gcd(f,X^N-1)=1$. This is because $(X-1) \mid (X^N-1)$ for every $N \geq 1$, and also $(X-1) \mid f$ for $f \in L_g$ with $f \neq 0$ because we have $f(1) = 0$.
While typing this question, I have noticed that this might be a known error in the original paper, because the textbook An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography by the same authors defines $f$ as a polynomial with exactly $d+1$ coefficients equal to $1$ and $d$ coefficients equal to $-1$. Such a polynomial may have an inverse.

Question about the multiple transmission attack:

In Section 3.3, the authors describe an attack which involves computing $h^{-1}$. It is not very clear in the paper, but I understand this inverse as the inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_q[X]/(X^N-1)$ (and maybe this is my misunderstanding?). However, $h$ cannot have an inverse in this ring, because it is a multiple of $g$ and, just like above, we have $(X-1) \mid g$.
Is the NTRU scheme still vulnerable to a multiple transmission attack?
[HPS98] https://ntru.org/f/hps98.pdf


Section 2.2 defines $\mathcal L(d_1,d_2)$ to be the polynomials in $\mathcal F_q$ with exactly $d_1$ +1 coefficients and exactly $d_2$ -1 coefficients and the rest 0. $\mathcal L_g$ is defined to be $\mathcal L(d_g,d_g)$, which matches your definition and is indeed the sample space for $g$. However, $f$ is drawn from a different distribution $\mathcal L(d_f,d_f-1)$. In particular this will guarantee that $f(1)=1$ and hence that $f$ is likely to be invertible.

It is true that $h$ does not have the required inverse. However, there is a trivial reduction map down to the $\mathbb Z_q[X]/(X^{N-1}+\cdots+1)$ which allows us to remove the factor of $X-1$ from $h$. In this ring the reduction of $h$ is likely to be invertible and hence we can recover the reduction of $\phi_i-\phi_1$ in this smaller ring, which still allows us to recover some coefficients of (or at least information about) $\phi_1$.


